# How to create a slideshow before showing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to find a way in order to create a slideshow and specify the timing between each picture. Then after the sequence, I want to display/reveal the home page.

I don't really have a lot of JavaScript experience so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To answer the title question, you'd use Java, not JavaScript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here is one simple/basic example:

```js
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse; /* Just a helper */
var slideshowContainer = $('.slideshow');
var slideshowItems = slideshowContainer.find('.item').reverse();
var slideshowItemsTotal = slideshowItems.length;
slideshowItems.each(function(i) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        thisItem.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            thisItem.remove();
            if( i+1==slideshowItemsTotal ) {
                slideshowContainer.remove();
            };
        });
    }, i*5000+4000);
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0 none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slideshow {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.slideshow .item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Page header</h1>
<p>Page content.</p>
<div class="slideshow">
    <img class="item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/00ff00/333" />
    <img class="item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/ff0000/111" />
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rxcv7h8/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeout function to put timing between every function. Then change the pictures with functions to make it look like it is a slideshow.

Example: calls the function after 3 seconds to make an alert.

```
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
```

You can find millions of examples on google for timing with JS.

Good luck